# avoid sql inject by query string in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, response.redirect, redirecttoaction

I programed an application with asp.net and use "respons.redirect" in some pages, like this:

```
Response.Redirect(string.Format("~/*****/****.aspx?ID={0}", ID));
```

as user execute this cod he will redirect to correct page and every thing is fine .he can see this redirect link in his browser address :

```
http://localhost:1852/Jornal/Editor/ReviewerEmail.aspx?ID=1030
```

Now if he changes the ID manually and the ID is correct he can access the other data without any permission. how can i avoid this problem?(I wont use session)
please help me

Comment: This has nothing to do with SQL injection.

Comment: @SLaks Absolutely correct. But what do you want to bet the OP does have an SQL injection vulnerability, too? ;)

Comment: Before you do **any** web development, read and understand https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project.

Comment: Ok thanks. so it seems that i should change my programming..:)

Comment: so any solution for this problem?! ;(

Comment: Add a column in your table which will identify logged-in users.Suppose user A access ID from 1000 to 2000 and user B access ID from 2000-2500 & so on.

Comment: @SaeedTalaee: Make sure to put in a private (securely random) key for the hash; otherwise, it will be completely useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the ID needs to be public and no access control can solve the problem.

then i would suggest that you add a second parameter that is a hash of that Id.
Tampering with the ID parameter will cause a missmatch between ID and hash

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256.aspx

you cold also change your ID parameter to a less 'guessable' id, like a GUID

Comment: Attackers can compute the hash by themselves.  You need HMAC.

Comment: Yes, SHA256 is an HMAC digest algorithm. And any hash or crypt can be cracked. But this just might be beyond the scope and intended implementation of this question

Comment: No; SHA256 is _not_ an HMAC algorithm.  You need http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha256.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You need to use **access control**.

Whenever you display any data, you need to check whether the currently-logged-in user has access to that data.

Obviously, you also need to track the currently-logged-in user, in a way that will prevent attackers from being able to claim they are someone else..
To do that, use ASP.Net's built-in membership system.